# Find average of every column in a dataframe, grouped by column, exluding one value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataframe like the one presented below:

```
    CPU Memory Disk  Label
0    21     28   29      0
1    46     53   55      1
2    48     45   49      2
3    48     52   50      3
4    51     54   55      4
5    45     50   56      5
6    50     83   44     -1
```

What I want is to `grouby` and find the average of each label. So far I have this
`dataset.groupby('Label')['CPU', 'Memory', 'Disk'].mean()` which works just fine and get the results as follows:

```
Label           CPU     Memory       Disk 
    -1     46.441176  53.882353  54.176471
     0     48.500000  58.500000  60.750000
     1     45.000000  51.000000  60.000000
     2     54.000000  49.000000  56.000000
     3     55.000000  71.500000  67.500000
     4     53.000000  70.000000  71.000000
     5     21.333333  30.000000  30.666667
```

The only thing I haven't yet found is how to exclude everything that is labeled as `-1`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the dataframe before grouping:

```
# Exclude rows with Label=-1
dataset = dataset.loc[dataset['Label'] != -1]

# Group by on filtered result
dataset.groupby('Label')['CPU', 'Memory', 'Disk'].mean()
```